# IUserValidator for IdentityUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I have custom user email validator for Identity user manager.

It was created for validation user Email based on additional property IsDeleted(new users can be added with email of deleted user).

This is how it looks.

```
public class UserEmailValidator<TUser> : IUserValidator<TUser>
    where TUser : UserAuth
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    public UserEmailValidator(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityResult> ValidateAsync(UserManager<TUser> manager, TUser user)
    {
        var errors = new List<IdentityError>();

        var existingAccount = await _unitOfWork.AuthUsers.Get()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(u => u.NormalizedEmail == user.Email.ToUpper() && !u.IsDeleted);
        if (existingAccount != null)
            errors.Add(new IdentityError() { Code = GlobalData.Translations.IdentityKeys.DuplicateEmail });

        return errors.Any()
            ? IdentityResult.Failed(errors.ToArray())
            : IdentityResult.Success;
    }
}
```

When I use method `var res1 = await userManager.CreateAsync(newUser)` it works as expected.
The value of res1 is Succeed.

But actually ValidateAsycn method calls as well when user is assigning to role

```
var res2 = await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(newUser, "admin")
```

and the result of res2 is Failed, because of duplicated email.
Is there a way to clarify what the action is going to be validated(user creation, adding to role or any other type of action), to provide correct validation for all cases?

Here is the setup from `Startup.cs`

```
var userBuilder = services.AddIdentity<UserAuth, Role>(options =>
{
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = GlobalData.CustomClaimNames.UserId;
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
.AddUserValidator<UserEmailValidator<UserAuth>>()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddEmailAndPasswordConfimationTotpTokenProvider();
```

UPD:

```
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
await _userManager.RemovePasswordAsync(user);
```

as well call same ValidateAsync method

Comment: Did you use `.AddUserValidator<UserEmailValidator<UserTypeHere>>` in Services in `.AddIdentity`? You may also need to replace the built-in user validation using `services.Replace`

Comment: @jeuxjeux20 Yes, I use `.AddUserValidator`. Please check it, I've just added it to question description. ❝You may also need to replace the built-in user validation using services.Replace❞. Do you have/know any examples?

Comment: @ovasylenko Something like this: `ervices.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Scoped<IUserValidatior<UserTypeHere>, UserEmailValidator<UserTypeHere>>());` that you can put after the whole `AddIdentity` statement

Comment: @jeuxjeux20. Thanks! I've got it. But I think it's different from what I need. I still have same issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to clarify what the action is going to be validated...?

There's no context for a call to `ValidateUser`, except for the `User` itself, which means there's no real way to know exactly *why* it's being invoked.

`UserManager` contains a `protected` method ([`ValidateAsync`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L2469)) that is called internally whenever `UserManager.CreateAsync` or `UserManager.UpdateUserAsync` is called. A call to `AddToRoleAsync` results in a call to `UpdateUserAsync`, which ends up with `ValidateAsync` running through the implementations of `IUserValidator<TUser>` to perform the validation.

The implementation of the built-in [`UserValidator<TUser>`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserValidator.cs#L16) that you've replaced handles your problem with the following check ([source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserValidator.cs#L95)):

```
var owner = await manager.FindByEmailAsync(email);
if (owner != null && 
    !string.Equals(await manager.GetUserIdAsync(owner), await manager.GetUserIdAsync(user)))
{
    errors.Add(Describer.DuplicateEmail(email));
}
```

First, it checks whether or not there's an existing account with that email address and then checks whether or not that account is the same as the one being validated. If it's the same, it's not a duplicate.

This all means that you should be able to extend your check to perform similar logic. For example:

```
var existingAccount = await _unitOfWork.AuthUsers.Get().FirstOrDefaultAsync(u =>
    u.NormalizedEmail == user.Email.ToUpper() &&
    !u.IsDeleted &&
    u.Id != user.Id);
```

Here, I've added `u.Id != user.Id`, which is a lot less involved than the built-in implementation as your code knows it's working with `UserAuth` and can use its properties directly.